# What happened to this ocean?

Tags: terraria

I actually don't understand what happened here, but there are no oceans in this world. I have finally gotten to expert mode and I wanted to fight Duke Fishron, then I noticed that there is no ocean event on either side of the map. Do you guys have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing this is an unfortunate world and the ocean didn't generate properly.  Maybe try another expert mode game and see if the ocean is there or not. I don't think expert mode manipulates the ocean in any way, but at least you can double check.

Comment: @TimmyJim You're correct. World gen is a fallible RNG: sometimes the ocean wont generate properly. Dragon, did you let the entire generation process complete, or did you interrupt it by closing the program at all?

Answer (score 11):

I believe the ocean biome requirements are met here as there are more than two tiles tall of water over sand and is located at the edge of the map. In other words, it was bad RNG that provided you with an ocean that is not ideal.

You can create the ocean biome there by adding more water to the basin. You can duplicate water by placing blocks in a J shape or ∴ shape. Spam click the water bucket to place water on the hook of the J or the top block of the ∴. I suggest using the ∴ and expanding the pattern outward to allow for more water to be placed at once, speeding up the process.

You will need somewhere around a thousand tiles of connected water for it to count as fishing in the ocean biome.

Comment: Instead of manually adding water, you could create a pump system and have it done automatically using a timer (or more complicated trigger system).

Comment: @pavel Since he is at the beginning of expert mode, I am assuming he does not have access to pumps yet.

Comment: yes thank you for your suggestion and I made a artifcial ocean biome but when fish for duke fishron it doest spawn but thank you kindy for the ans

Comment: @BanhMiDacBiet Screenshots may be more helpful than the dots you've provided.

Comment: Does the game show any messages when you fish with the truffle worm?